# Import vue js file to laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I used [these vue js files](https://github.com/Krutie/distraction-free-vue-form) to build my form in Larval.

When I call these files in Larval I get a blank page.

The structure of my files is as follows:

[image: tree file show]

And the contents of `app.js` file is as follow:

```
import Vue from "vue"
import App from "./components/App.vue"
import store from "./components/store"
import VeeValidate from "vee-validate"
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
import "./components/directives"
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Of course, I get the below warning when I run `nmp run watch`'s command.

> WARNING in ./resources/js/app.js 5:8-19 "export 'default' (imported as
>   'VeeValidate') was not found in 'vee-validate'  @ multi
>   ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

My question is: *How to import external vue js files to laravel project?*

Comment: I solved the warning using of `import * as VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';`

Comment: have you added package of `vee-validate`?

Comment: @JinalSomaiya Yes i added that package and the warning solved but the blank page not resolved.

Comment: @JinalSomaiya I copy the `vue js files` from the git and put them in the `resource folder` and called in the `app.js`. Is this right?

Comment: yes that is right but laravel how know about vuejs file?

Comment: @JinalSomaiya Thanks for continuing help. Can you explain a little more? I don't understand 'laravel how know about vuejs file'

Comment: `vee-validate` don't have a default export, look at the source code [here](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/master/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to include app.js to your blade file like this

```
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

after that if you want to use vue js components in you blade app you need to define them in your `app.js` like this:

```
Vue.component('home', require('path to your component').default);
```

and in your blade under `div #idd` add your tag `<home></home>`

Answer (score 0):

> use src="**{{ mix('js/app.js') }}**"

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <title>VueJS CRUD Operations in Laravel</title>
    <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    
    <div id="app">
        
    </div>

    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem , try to use vue-router version 3 using :

```js
npm install vue-router@3
```

that is working fine with me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).